# Android how to avoid i/o problems when periodically writing to a file on internal memory

Tags: java, android, file-io, io

I'm writing an app which records various sensor (location for one) and device specific meta data to a file and then transmits the file to a server.  It is not a background service - the app only needs to write and transmit files while the app is active (no need to set alarms to wake up a service).  I'd like to write a row to the file every time `onLocationChanged()` is called (though location data is not the only data being written) - or at least at a similar rate at which `onLocationChanged()` is called.  `onLocationChanged()` is currently being called once/second, but we may end up recording data at a higher rate (possibly 2-3x/second).  That seems like a fair amount of i/o to the internal memory.

I currently have everything working (proof of concept), but I need to improve on the methods I'm using to write to the file.  I'm writing a row to the file each time `onLocationChanged()` is called, which is probably not wise and it seems is causing i/o to stack up.  I've read other similar questions which touch on various methods (new threads, alarms, timer tasks, handlers, etc.), but I couldn't locate answers that were specific to what I'm trying to do.  I've also considered other methods like caching/buffering data and only writing to internal storage on a less frequent basis (every 10 seconds?), or possibly writing to a SQLite db and exporting to a file later.  What can I do to best uncouple (assuming that's what I need to do) the file code from the sensor code and ensure timely updates to the file?  I also need to ensure that all data gets written to the file.

UPDATE:
The solution I ended up using involves appending to a StringBuilder for a set number of rows (one row per call to onLocationChanged()).  After appending 10 rows worth of data, effectively buffering, I'm handing off the StringBuilder to an AsyncTask, where the data is written to file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The recommendation is to do all file I/O on a separate thread. You can set up a producer/consumer structure, where the producer is the UI thread that generates write requests to a queue and the consumer is a worker thread that wakes up when a write request is queued and updates the file/data base/whatever.

This will work unless your definition of "timely updates" is rather strict. However, since you are considering queueing things for 10 seconds, my guess is that this is not an issue.

EDIT: 
To deal with the queue possibly backing up, you should arrange for the consumer to process everything on the queue whenever it wakes up. If the I/O simply cannot keep up, even with batch processing like that, you could arrange for the queue to drop elements once it hits a maximum size. You might also need to reduce the frequency at which `onLocationChanged()` is called.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the actual question - sure, a thread is probably part of the implementation - but none of the "what should it try to do" issues are addressed - just moving a "data available" triggered write to a background thread will have minimal impact to anything except UI responsiveness.

Comment: I should clarify - I'd rather not buffer/queue the writes for 10 seconds if it's possible to avoid that

Comment: @rsg - If the data are being generated faster than the I/O can process them, then some sort of buffering is needed (or you need to be willing to drop data, or both). There was nothing magical about 10 seconds; presumably data could be written faster than that. However, you do need to deal with the mismatch in capacity. I added a couple of ideas to my answer concerning this.

Answer (score 2):

Have been in a somewhat similar situation during a pervasive positioning course.

Here is what we did:

**FileWriter**
The writing to file part was not an issue for us as we only collected GPS locations and not other sensor data. For us an implementation like below was sufficient. It is not clear if you have to write the data to the same file, if not, then you should be able to use it directly.

```
public class FileOutputWriter {


private static String pathString = "";
    private static String sensorString = "";

public static void setPath(Context context, String path) {
    pathString = path;
    File pathFile = new File(pathString);
    pathFile.mkdirs();
}


public static void writeData(String data, String sensor, boolean append) {

    File file = new File(pathString + "/" + sensor+ ".log");

    long timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis();

    BufferedWriter out = null;
    try {
        out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, append));
            out.write(timeStamp + ":" + data);

        out.newLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            out.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Uploader**
To upload data to the server we create a cue of LogEntries (change this to your own dataholder object or simply String).

```
public class DataLogger {

static Vector<LogEntry> log = new Vector<LogEntry>();


public static void addEnty(LogEntry entry) {
    Log.d("DEBUG", entry.getStrategy() + " added position to logger " + entry.getLocation());
    log.add(entry);
}

public static Vector<LogEntry> getLog() {
    return log;
}

public static void clear() {
    log.clear();
}
}
```

Notice that Vector is thread-safe.

Finally we implemented a UploaderThread, responsible for periodically inspecting the DataLogger cue and upload added entries.

```
public class UploaderThread extends Thread {


public static LinkedList<String> serverLog = new LinkedList<String>();


Boolean stop = false;
Context c;



public UploaderThread(Context c) {
    this.c = c;
}

public void pleaseStop() {
    stop = true;
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(!stop) {

        try {               
            if(DataLogger.log.size() > 0 && Device.isOnline(c)) {
                while(DataLogger.log.size() > 0) {

                    LogEntry logEntry = DataLogger.getLog().get(0);
                    String result = upload(logEntry);
                    serverLog.add("("+DataLogger.log.size()+")"+"ServerResponse: "+result);

                    if(result != null && result.equals("OK")) {
                        DataLogger.getLog().remove(0);
                    } else {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    }
                }
            } else {
                serverLog.add("Queue size = ("+DataLogger.log.size()+") + deviceIsonline: "+Device.isOnline(c));
            }

            Thread.sleep(10000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private String upload(LogEntry entry) {
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://yoururl/commit.php");      

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tracename",sessionName +"-"+ entry.getStrategy().toString()));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("latitude", Double.toString(entry.getLocation().getLatitude())));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("longitude", Double.toString(entry.getLocation().getLongitude())));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("timestamp", Long.toString(entry.getTimestamp())));

        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        if(response != null) {
            InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
            String responseContent = inputStreamToString(in);

            return responseContent;
        }
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       


    return null;
}


private String inputStreamToString(InputStream is) throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();

    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

    // Read response until the end
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
        total.append(line); 
    }

    // Return full string
    return total.toString();
}

}
```

The thread is simply started in the first activity of your app:

```
    UploaderThread ut;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    FileOutputWriter.setPath(this, Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            .getAbsolutePath());

    ut = new UploaderThread(this);
    ut.start();
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    ut.pleaseStop();
}
```

Hope this gets you on the way

Comment: Thanks @cYrixmorten this is helpful and similar to what I'm trying to do.  I'm following your code but a couple questions if you don't mind: Where are you calling `FileOutputWriter.writeData()` - are you calling this from `onLocationChanged()` in your main activity?  Same question for `DataLogger.addEntry()`?  I'm probably a little confused because I don't see what you're doing in `onLocationChanged()`.

Comment: Well, you are right I did not include that in my code. The reason for this is that we had a handful of different setups with different purposes. But, I would think that for your app doing both in onLocationChanged() would make sense.

Comment: Thank you - my primary issue was related to avoiding file I/O problems during writes, but your sample code was helpful in thinking through a threaded upload process.